# Property names are not available for my datagrid column bindings

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Just beginning to learn DataGrid in WPF XAML. This is the code:

Model

```
Public Class Idea
  Public Property IdeaID() As Integer
  Public Property Name() As String
End Class
```

ViewModel

```
Public Class IdeaViewModel
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Public Shared Property allIdeas() As New ObservableCollection(Of Idea)

  Public Sub New()
    For index = 1 To 10
      Dim anitem As New Idea
      anitem.Name = "Value " & index
      allIdeas.Add(anitem)
    Next
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property AddAnItemToList() As ICommand
    Get
      Return New RelayCommand(AddressOf InsertAnItem)
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Sub InsertAnItem()
    Dim anItem As New Idea
    anItem.Name = "Item " & allIdeas.Count()
    allIdeas.Add(anItem)
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property ClearTheList() As ICommand
    Get
      Return New RelayCommand(AddressOf ClearStoredList)
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Sub ClearStoredList()
    allIdeas.Clear()
  End Sub


  Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler _
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

View (XAML only, no code behind)

```
<Window x:Class="IdeaView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"        
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM7"
        Title="IdeaView" Height="500" Width="200" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:IdeaViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
      <Button Margin="25" Height="50" Content="Insert an item"    Command="{Binding AddAnItemToList}"/>
      <Button Margin="25" Height="50" Content="Clear stored list" Command="{Binding ClearTheList}"/>

    <DataGrid Height="100"
              ItemsSource="{Binding allIdeas}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              >
    </DataGrid>

    <DataGrid Height="100"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              >
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding allIdeas}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding allIdeas}"/>
    </DataGrid>

  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The first DataGrid comes up fine.  The second DataGrid of course does not because you can't bind a column to the entire `allIdeas` object.  I just left that code in to point out where I know I want something like `"{Binding Name}"`, but the way I'm binding the DataGrid isn't correct & I haven't been able to locate a post that addresses this topic at such a basic level.

I'm trying to work my way up to 2-way binding in a DataGrid but I wanted to be sure I understand how the data is connecting first.  That's why I'm trying to manually bind the properties of the ViewModel's ObservableCollection to the columns in a DataGrid.

Comment: What do you want to have in the second data grid?

Comment: Exactly the same thing that is in the first auto-generated grid, except I want to see how I can specify each column manually in XAML code.

Comment: Ohhhh right. Ok.

Comment: I adjusted the ViewModel code posted above to make it convenient to simply copy the Model, ViewModel and XAML and immediately have it run in a WPF project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm modifying AQuirky's answer, but he seems to have wandered off at the moment. And his answer's got an error in it.

```
<DataGrid Height="100"
          ItemsSource="{Binding allIdeas}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdeaID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: That works. It was the `<DataGrid.Columns>` element that I was missing.  One of those rookie dumb oversights.  Thanks so much.  BTW, something jumped/adjusted in the SO system and the posted answers shifted around.  Anyway, problem solved.  I'll continue on my journey of discovery until the next question.

Comment: @Alan The answers rearrange according to voting and acceptance. Glad you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<DataGrid Height="100"
          ItemsSource="{Binding allIdeas}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          >
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IdeaID}"/>
  <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I did try this with no success but just tried it again.  It throws an exception at the Binding keyword for the first DataGridTextColumn.  The intellisense is popping up the same set of choices as shown for the first Binding up in the DataGrid element.  I know sometimes we don't see everything in intellisense, but I think in this case I should see the collection's properties show up, yes?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @Alan what if you add Mode=OneWay to the column bindings?

Comment: `'Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' threw an exception.'`.  This occurred with the simple change above.  However, I did determine that the ItemsSource assignment is involved.  If I simply remove that assignment, the exception does not get thrown.

Comment: @Alan Try my version of AQuirky's answer. I just realized what that exception probably means. It's treating those DataGridTextColumns as items in the grid's collection, not as columns for the columns collection.